# UIModalView Dismisses stranger when keyboard is active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, keyboard, modal-dialog

I'm having a strange issue with my modal view. The modal view asks for some user input so the keyboard pops on. When I click the cancel button to dismiss while the keyboard is still active they both dismiss in an animated fashion but the modal jerks to the right first, very strange. What would be my best course of action here? Would it be to disable my cancel modal button when the keyboard is active? If so how do I go about detecting the presents of the keyboard?

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen the same kind of bug, I think it was because I dismissed the container of the modal instead of the modal itself or some such. In short: try to check whether you are dismissing the right VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the presence of keyboard using NSNotification Class. Hope this helps